# Lenovo S21e recovery

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, lenovo

I was able to find a Lenovo S21e cheap.  I was able to get the WiFi and mouse working thanks to the posts on that (and will get more practice since I reflashed the system).

My question (which may extend beyond this model) is can this device (running windows 8.1) out of the box boot without the recovery partition?  I would like to keep the win8 on the system for future use, but I cannot remove the recovery portion from windows disk manager, so I used gpart on the live CD (15.10) to remove the partition in order to make more space.  If I can keep the system running windows on dual boot without the recovery partition I want to do that, but if I have to tie up 20% of the hard drive to simply boot windows, I will wipe windows entirely.

I have established the following for those interested:

1. I can dual-boot with windows in UEFI and Ubuntu in legacy by switching the load priority in BIOS instead of using Grub.
2. I wanted to remove the recovery partition on a UEFI load side by side, but I assumed that the process damaged the boot record, but everything I tried failed to get windows back.
3. I restored windows with a USB thumb drive merely removed the recovery portion, no ubuntu install at all, and now windows does not load.  I am specifically getting the 0xc0000225 error.

Bottom line question: am I missing something or can this computer not load windows without the recovery partition?